# moving a long text in textview with animation

Tags: android, jquery-animate, textview, marquee

I want to make a line to view news continuously repeated, I am do it but in some devices the moving of text is very slow, how can i make it faster, This is my code:

```
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
  android:scrollHorizontally="true"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vim viderer saperet ei, error solet nonumy vim an, dicit tation erroribus cum ut. Te eos probo ferri mucius. "
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:textSize="12dp" />

     TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, and if you have time to play, you could draw the text yourself after in the onDraw method of a TextView extended custom class :
[onDraw guide](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

You would need to draw text in the onDraw canvas :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)